# Looped, reversible animation using Core Animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, core-animation, cabasicanimation

In my iOS 5 app I have a custom `UIButton` that has a red orb as its image. When the button is tapped I would like the orb to start pulsing/fading between red and green. I have both red and green images and can successfully cross-disolve between the two using the following code:

```
CABasicAnimation *imageSwitchAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];       
imageSwitchAnimation.fromValue = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"].CGImage;
imageSwitchAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"].CGImage;
imageSwitchAnimation.duration = 1.5f;        
[self.button.imageView.layer addAnimation:imageSwitchAnimation forKey:@"animateContents"];
```

However, I would like the animation to continue forever (well, until I tell it to stop) and also for the animation to reverse and loop. In other words, fade red -> green -> red and then repeat.

I tried putting the animation block above into an endless loop (together with some logic to determine whether the fading should go from red -> green or green -> red) but this just locks-up the entire app.

Other solutions seem to use Cocos2d, which seems fairly heavy-weight since this is the only animation I need in the app (so I don't want to use such frameworks unless absolutely needed).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, right within `CABasicAnimation`.  The trick is that many of its most important methods are not in the [CABasicAnimation Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), or even in its superclasses.  CABasicAnimation implements a protocol called `CAMediaTiming`.  See the [CAMediaTiming Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CAMediaTiming).

You want to know about two properties in particular: `autoreverses` and `repeatCount`.  Both are self-explanatory, but what if you want infinite repeats?  From the entry for `repeatCount`:

> May be fractional. If the repeatCount is 0, it is ignored. Defaults to 0. If both repeatDuration and repeatCount are specified the behavior is undefined.
>
> Setting this property to HUGE_VALF will cause the animation to repeat forever.

Can you work it out from there?

Comment: Thanks so much - this works perfectly! Very clearly explained too :)

Comment: you can also use the macro INFINITY, which in math.h is: #define INFINITY    HUGE_VALF